# XSLT Coding issue

Tags: xml, xslt

Expected outPut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Tablix1>
    <SIDCode_Collection>
        <SIDCode SIDCode="854-2013-17011949">
            <PName_Collection>
                <PName PName="Test1" />
                <PName PName="Test2" />
            </PName_Collection>
        </SIDCode>
        <SIDCode SIDCode="854-2013-17011950">
            <PName_Collection>
                <PName PName="Test3" />
                <PName PName="Test4" />
            </PName_Collection>
        </SIDCode>
    </SIDCode_Collection>
</Tablix1>
```

I have written the XSLT code to convert the SSR report output mentioned as  above output. 
But I am not able to get the output as expected. Can some one please help me to find the issue ?

Currently this is giving only SIDCode. But it is not giving the respective Pname results in the XML output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="SampleXML">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="a:Report/a:Tablix1/a:SIDCode_Collection/a:SIDCode">
        <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">

            <xsl:for-each select="@SIDCode">
                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>

                    <xsl:for-each select="a:PName_Collection/a:PName">
                            <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                                <xsl:for-each select="@PName">
                                    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@PName"/>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post the input, so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the example Input : I want to get the SIDCode PNAME Result, PNAME RESULT <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xsi:schemaLocation="SampleXML http://reportserver?%2FSampleXML&amp;rs%3AFormat=XML&amp;rc%3ASchema=True" Name="SampleXML" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="SampleXML">
 <Tablix1>
  <SIDCode_Collection>
   <SIDCode SIDCode="854-2013-17011949">
    <PName_Collection>
     <PName PName="TestA" Result=0/>
     <PName PName="TestB" Result="Absence" />
    </PName_Collection>
   </SIDCode>
  </SIDCode_Collection>
 </Tablix1>
</Report>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments - edit your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Without the source XML it is hard to guess, but I think at least one problem is the following:

With the line `<xsl:for-each select="@SIDCode">` you set your attribute "SIDCode" as the context node. Then, inside the foreach loop you try to access the node `a:PName_Collection/a:PName`. That can't work, because `a:PName_Collection/a:PName` is obviously no child node of the attribute node `@SIDCode`. I'd suggest removing the `@` in `<xsl:for-each select="@SIDCode">` and accessing the attribute node in the XPath expressions in `<xsl:element name="{name(.)}">`and `<xsl:value-of select="."/>`.

Comment: Here is the example:In the mentioned XSLT there are two collections . so fitst collection SID and I am taking the respective value from <xsl:for-each select="@SIDCode">
                <xsl:element name="{name(.)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/> After that one sid can have mutiple Pnames .so I am trying to loop all Pname after first SID prints. Above is the same input and that is the expected output as well. Because I am trying to convert the SSRS report output as XML.